# Firebase Sorting Score from Highest to Lowest ~ Android

Tags: android, sorting, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Inside `MainActivity`, I have this function:

```
 public void sortingData() {

    mRootRef = new Firebase("https://fyp-1-43a27.firebaseio.com/User");
    dbSortAllData = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

    ListView mLvScore = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvScore);

    final List<UserInformation> listScore = new LinkedList<>();
    final ArrayAdapter<UserInformation> adapter
            = new ArrayAdapter<UserInformation>
            (this, R.layout.scoreboard_row, listScore) {

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
            if (view == null) {
                view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.scoreboard_row, parent, false);
            }

            UserInformation item = listScore.get(position);
            ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvScoreName)).setText(item.getName());
            ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvScorePoint)).setText(item.getScore());
            return view;
        }
    };
    mLvScore.setAdapter(adapter);

    com.firebase.client.Query queryRef = mRootRef.orderByChild("score").startAt("score").endAt("score").limitToFirst(50);
    queryRef.addChildEventListener(new com.firebase.client.ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(com.firebase.client.DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            UserInformation sI = dataSnapshot.getValue(UserInformation.class);
            listScore.add(sI);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(com.firebase.client.DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(com.firebase.client.DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(com.firebase.client.DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

My Model Class:

```
public class UserInformation implements Comparable<UserInformation> {

    public String name;
    public String age;
    public String score;

    public UserInformation() {}

    public UserInformation(String name, String age, String score) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.score = score;
    }

    // ... Getters and Setters here. 
}
```

These piece of code works, it sorts from lowest to highest.

My Problem is how do I sort it from Highest to Lowest? Suggestions and advises are much appreciated.

Comment: Firebase sorts lexicographically, AFAIK. You can just reverse the ArrayAdapter's data

Comment: Why are you using https://firebase.com instead of https://firebase.google.com ? firebase.com is deprecated.

Comment: Collections.sort(scores, new Comparator<Score>() {

        public int compare(Score o1, Score o2) {
            return o2.getScores().get(0).compareTo(o1.getScores().get(0));
        }
    });


Above code is what i found on the internet, but i dont really know how to fit it in.. any guidance appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reorder the data on the client side - just reverse the list.

Edit :
When you want to reverse the list, you can use :

```
Collections.reverse(listScore);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

You can also just add each element that you get from the database to the front of the list to get it in reverse order :

```
public void onChildAdded(com.firebase.client.DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
        UserInformation sI = dataSnapshot.getValue(UserInformation.class);
        listScore.addFirst(sI);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

And change the declaration of listScore to :

```
final LinkedList<UserInformation> listScore = new LinkedList<>();
```

Comment: @AbAppletic: if you have a better answer, provide it as an answer please.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I know how to do it with a RecyclerView but not with a ListView. Still, this answer doesn't have enough information...

Comment: Hi rhari, thanks for replying this question. I have found this method but i dont seems getting the ideal of fitting it into my method, could you be more specify on how show I wrote it? guidance is much appreciated

Comment: Edited my answer, have a look.

Comment: Thanks Rhari, sorry for disturbing your precious time to help solving my problem..... much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

if you want in reverse order then create one extra key and store that newKey = value(multiplied by)-1 than do simple order by.
I have tried other solution by reversing ArrayList but when you add new data to existing list then it will get worst.

[As you can see my priority score in negative so I can write](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Uxi4.png)

databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
.child("node").child("event").orderByChild("priorityScore");

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please make your answer more comprehensible by adding sample code. It would be extremely helpful if you add an updated version of the code in the question to your answer.